# Can remote URL instead of a name be used to check out branches?

Tags: git

`git checkout -b <name> <remote>/<branch>` seems to require a named remote. Is there a way to make it work given only an URL? The reason is that people on the team have different names for remotes (e.g. `gitlab` and `origin` vs `origin` and `github`), and I'd like to ignore that difference in a script.

One possibility is to give the name to the remote in the beginning of the script and delete it in the end, but I'd prefer to avoid it.

Comment: If the name of the branch is unique, you can skip `<remote>` altogether.

Comment: Maybe the team should adopt some standard naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not any way to make the second parameter of `git checkout -b` work with a URL as opposed to the name of a branch (in the form of `<remote>/<branch>` or otherwise).

From the man page:

```
   git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]
       Specifying -b causes a new branch to be created as if git-branch(1) were
       called and then checked out. In this case you can use the --track or
       --no-track options, which will be passed to git branch. As a convenience,
       --track without -b implies branch creation; see the description of
       --track below.

       If -B is given, <new_branch> is created if it doesn’t exist; otherwise,
       it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of

           $ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
           $ git checkout <branch>

       that is to say, the branch is not reset/created unless "git checkout" is
       successful.
```

The second parameter to `git branch` referred to as `start point` needs to be something that points to a commit in the existing repo. A branch (which is possibly not even fetched) addressed by URL will not achieve this. Moreover there is no way to encode a branch into a git URL as standard (github might have something, but I think not, else golang imports would be a lot easier ...)

If you want to make this work, you will need to:

- Parse the output of `git remote -v show` to get the appropriate remote name
- Execute a `git fetch` to ensure the relevant branch is pulled down (`git fetch --all` is probably your friend)
- Append the branch name to the remote name, and `git checkout -b` that.

Here's a very lightly tested bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# usage: scriptname repo branchname
#
# where repo is the URL, branchname is the branchname to create
repo="$1"
branchname="$2"
remote=$(git remote -v show | perl -n -e 'if (m,^(\w+)\s+(\S+)\b, && $2 eq '"'${repo}'"') {print "$1\n" ; exit 0}')
if [ "$remote" == "" ] ; then
    echo cannot find "${repo}" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
git fetch --all && git checkout -b "${branchname}" "remotes/${remote}/${branchname}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Running `git remote` in a repo root for example gives you something like this:

```
$ git remote
foobar
origin
```

You could parse that and incorporate it in your script.

Comment: good idea, but vague answer. It doesn't explain how to infer the remote name given a URL.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (as suggested by others) is to get the remote's name given its URL

```
REMOTE_URL=git@github.com:foo/bar.git
REMOTE_NAME=git remote -v show | grep $REMOTE_URL | awk '{print $1}'
git checkout -b <name> $REMOTE_NAME/<branch>
```

Also, if you're lucky enough to have a unique name for the branch, you can simply do

```
git checkout -b <name> <branch>
```

and git will automatically pick the remote containing that branch.

Comment: ... unless your URL has regular expression characters in. `grep -F` would be better. I overengineered this in `perl`.

Comment: @abligh, fair point. This is more like a concept, the actual parsing can be more solid depending on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but not using `git checkout` alone. Gerrit uses the following command to let everyone checkout any branch (it uses some special refs, but the rest still applies):

`git fetch <url> branch && git checkout -b name FETCH_HEAD`